# How does this function inside a decorator work in Python?

Tags: python, function, decorator

```
def title_decorator(print_name_function):
#in addition to printing name it will print a title
    def wrapper():
        #it will wrap print_my_name with some functionality
        print("Professor:")
        print_name_function() #<----- QUESTION HERE
        #wrapper will print out professor and then call print_name_function
    return wrapper

def print_my_name():
    print("Joseph")

def print_mike():
    print("Mike")

decorated_function = title_decorator(print_mike)
#calling decorator function, passing in print_my_name

decorated_function
decorated_function()
```

Under `def wrapper()` we have `print_name_function()`, how does this work and why did we include `()` here?

I see we are passing in `print_name_function` into `title_decorator`

But I don't really understand how it was included in `def wrapper()` and what it means to include `()` behind `print_name_function()`

Comment: you questions is: how decorator know print_name_function or how this works overall ?

Comment: You passed the function `print_mike` as `print_name_function`, and `print_name_function()` (with parenthesis) *calls* the function. In Python, functions are objects, so you can pass them around by reference.

Comment: @Awdweaden Sorry I'm a bit confused. I thought functions needed to be defined for example: def print_my_name(). How is the parameter print_name_function actually a function?

Answer (score 1):

Think in a decorator like a function that return another function. What you want to do is add a behavior to a function without changing his implementation.

In practice that decorator have the following behavior.

```py
def title_decorator(print_name_function):

    # now your decorator have a local variable (print_name_function) 
    # in that function scope that variable is a reference to another 
    # function

    def wrapper():
        # now you write a function that do something

        print("Professor:")
        print_name_function() # here you function is calling a scope 
                              # variable that by the way is another 
                              # function. See that the scope of this 
                              # variable is *title_decorator*


    # now instead to return your argument function you return another
    # with some other behavior
    return wrapper
```

OBS: When *wrapper* is calling a function this is a reference to the object. Keep this is mind

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. I thought functions needed to be defined for example: def print_my_name(). How is the parameter print_name_function actually a function?

Comment: It's a reference to a function object. You define print_my_name in the main scope and send a reference to that function to title_decorator function. In that functions scope (title_decorator) the print_name_function reference the value of that reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply Decorator function is used to enhance the functionality of a function. read the comments of my code hope you understand this.**

````
def title_decorator(print_name_function):   # this function take one function as argument
    def wrapper(): # Here is Rapper function
        print("Professor:")
        print_name_function() #(<----- QUESTION HERE) Answer-----> We are calling the same function because without calling
                                    # doesn't work, basically the function we passed in title_decorator() calls print_name_function()
                                    # inside wrapper function,
        #wrapper will print out professor and then call print_name_function
    return wrapper

def print_my_name():
    print("Joseph")

def print_mike():
    print("Mike")


decorated_function = title_decorator(print_mike)    # Here you calling your function and give print_mike() function as an argument
                        # store it's returning value in variable named as decorated_function, so first time your decorator returns
                        # called wrapper() function
decorated_function()   # and then your variable become decorated_function is working as a function that's why you calling this```
````

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. I thought functions needed to be defined for example: def print_my_name(). How is the parameter print_name_function actually a function?